# I want to render dynamic HTML by function and uses v-for in these html

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a function to show some buttons and inside these buttons I want to use `v-for v-if` but if I done that in my function if I render it inside template `{{functionName()}}` it renders as text and if I render it as `v-html="functionName()"` the code inside the HTML `v-for v-if` not working

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you need to use simple v-show/v-if to show/hide your buttons. That's it